# WordPress theme Editor missing from Appearance menu

Tags: wordpress

I have been searching for the answer to this question and none of the fixes I find seem to work. I have already tried the following:

- Editing wp-config.php and/or functions.php and adjusting the line define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
- Installing the latest version of Wordpress
- Changing themes
- Deactivating all plugins
- iThemes Security adjustments (I don't have this on my Wordpress install)

Could it perhaps be something to do with my host? Any suggestions other than those listed above are appreciated.

Comment: So you've changed `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );` to false? there is no server caching ?

Comment: Actually that line never existed in my wp-config.php file to begin with. so that tip wasn't relevant to my situation. I tried adding that line and changing it to false. No change there either.

Comment: May be you are using Multisite mode? If so, you need to check http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/network/ , not website wp-admin itself

Comment: I'm not using Multisite mode, but thank you for the suggestion @Elvin85

Comment: Then the only way to solve it is manually checking the website. Because all possible reasons have been written here already